# CSS selector for elements with the same class as parent which works for any class

Tags: css

Is it possible to select elements with the same class as the parent element using CSS without explicitly writing the class name?

```
<div class="cl1">
   <div class="cl2">Text1</div>
   <div class="cl1">Text2</div>
   <div class="cl2">Text3</div>
   <div class="cl1">Text4</div>
   <div class="cl1">Text5</div>
</div>
```

For example, in this code, it should select child divs 2, 4 and 5. But I do not want write selector ***.cl1 .cl1{dislay: none;}*** since I have dozens of classes like this and I do not want to create identical selectors for each one.

Comment: No it is not...

Comment: Not without JavaScript